# WS02 Enrich mediator after end point call

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to use enrichment mediator to populate custom response from End point

my sequence

```
<sequence name="GetMySqlData" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">

    <enrich description="AddProductData">
        <source clone="true" type="inline">
            <ProductDataMySqlDB xmlns="">
                <code/>
                <name/>
                <description/>
                <qty/>
            </ProductDataMySqlDB>
        </source>
        <target action="child" xpath="//mediate"/>
    </enrich>
    <property expression="$ctx:ProductCode" name="code" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soapenv:Header/>
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <dat:getInventoryByCode>
                        <dat:code>$1</dat:code>
                    </dat:getInventoryByCode>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('code')"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="POST"/>
    <property name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="getInventoryByCode"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint key="getInventoryByCode"/>
    </call>

--PROBLEMS STARTS ---
    <enrich description="code">
        <source clone="true" xpath="//Entry/code"/>
        <target xpath="//mediate/ProductDataMySqlDB/code"/>
    </enrich>
    <enrich description="name">
        <source clone="true" xpath="//Body/Entries/Entry/name"/>
        <target xpath="//mediate/ProductDataMySqlDB/name"/>
    </enrich>
    <enrich description="description">
        <source clone="true" xpath="//Entries/Entry/description"    />
        <target xpath="//mediate/ProductDataMySqlDB/description"/>
    </enrich>
    <enrich description="qty">
        <source clone="true" xpath="//m0:Entries/m0:Entry/m0:qty"  xmlns:m0="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" />
        <target xpath="//mediate/ProductDataMySqlDB/qty"/>
    </enrich>
    <log level="full">
        <property expression="$body" name="MySQLResponse"/>
    </log>
    <loopback/>
</sequence>
```

response that I getting form endpoint is like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Entries xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
         <Entry>
            <code>PR2</code>
            <name>Product2</name>
            <description>Product stored in MySQL</description>
            <qty>-2</qty>
         </Entry>
      </Entries>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and the error in log are :
Specified node by xpath cannot be found. {org.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator}
Cannot Enrich message from an empty source. {org.apache.synapse.mediators.elementary.EnrichMediator}

so it looks like the xpath for my source  is wrong

```
<enrich description="code">
        <source clone="true" xpath="WHAT WOULD BE THE CORRECT PATH?"/>
        <target xpath="//mediate/ProductDataMySqlDB/code"/>
    </enrich>
```

thnks

Comment: So the sequence named "GetMySqlData" works with an input message corresponding to "response that I getting form endpoint", right ?  where do you see a node named "mediate" ?

Comment: yes I'm getting response from getInventoryByCode endpoint. About 'mediate' ... my reguest is like <root><mediate><ProductCode>PR2</ProductCode></mediate></root> ... so idea was to on end I can add child element under 'mediate' element  ...

Comment: the xpath used in the target section of enrich mediator must refer to an existing node in you current message

Comment: I will try it today  but I was still confusing about part '...  Cannot Enrich message from an empty source ...' I hope that enrich thing see my response form end point ... I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

In your message, 'Entry' and 'code' nodes belongs to a namespace "http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" (look at the 'Entries' root node) : you should declare and use this namespace in your source xpath :

```
<source xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" clone="true" xpath="//ds:Entry/ds:code"/>
```

Comment: first problem was that I found the <enrich description="AddProductData">
        <source clone="true" type="inline">
            <ProductDataMySqlDB>
                <code/>
                <name/>
                <description/>
                <qty/>
            </ProductDataMySqlDB>
        </source>
        <target action="child" type="body"/>!!!!!
    </enrich> and for that now (I bealive)  Im gething - Invalid Target object to be enrich ... for all result is same with or without NS

Comment: also shouldn't be like <source xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" clone="true" xpath="//ds:Entries/Entry/code"/  because only Entries has ns attribute ?

Comment: also ESB adding extra ns in it ?org.apache,synapse/xsd? <source clone="true" type="custom"
            xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
            xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="//ds:Entries/Entry/code"/>

Comment: Your problem with the target is because I guess there is no node named "mediate" in your message, so you can't injecte xml node under an unexisting node. Concerning the namespace, perhaps do you need to define it on the enrich node. Concerning the default synapse namespace you don't have to take care of it

Comment: in case <enrich>
        <source clone="false" type="body"/>
        <target action="replace" property="payload" type="property"/>
    </enrich> and log it like i'm getting the  income data = <ConsolidatedXMLRequest>
    <ProductCode>PR2</ProductCode>
</ConsolidatedXMLRequest> (I removed mediate element ) BUT if Im using  <enrich>
        <source clone="true" type="custom"
            xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="//ProductCode"/>
        <target action="replace" property="ReqCode" type="property"/>
    </enrich>
   no values in RegCode at all  ????